# $k(F_i)_{i=1}^{n}=k(G_j)_{j=1}^{m}$ iff there exist $a_i,b_j \in k$ such that $\langle F_i-a_i \rangle_{i=1}^{n} = \langle G_j-b_j \rangle_{j=1}^{m}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, fields, ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, for example $k=\mathbb{C}$ and let $F_1,\ldots,F_n,G_1,\ldots,G_m \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $n,m \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$.

**Claim:**

$\mathbb{C}(F_1,\ldots,F_n)=\mathbb{C}(G_1,\ldots,G_m)$ (fields of fractions)

if and only if

there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\langle F_1-a_1,\ldots,F_n-a_n \rangle = \langle G_1-b_1,\ldots,G_m-b_m\rangle$ (ideals).

> **Question:** Is the above claim true?

I have taken several examples where the claim was true. I could not find a counterexample.
The following are similar questions: [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723640/generalizing-a-result-in-mathbbcx-to-a-result-in-mathbbcx-y), [ii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), [iii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [iv](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4762684/f-g-h-k-in-mathbbcx-y-mathbbcf-g-mathbbch-k-imply-langle);
question [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723640/generalizing-a-result-in-mathbbcx-to-a-result-in-mathbbcx-y) answers one direcrion of my current question, I guess.

**Several examples:**

**(1)** $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y+x^3+7x^2+5x-1)$.

Then $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x,y+x^3+7x^2+5x-1+1 \rangle$, so $a_1=a_2=b_1=0, b_2=-1$.

Or $\langle x,y-1 \rangle=\langle x,y+x^3+7x^2+5x-1 \rangle$,
so $a_1=0,a_2=1,b_1=b_2=0$.

**(2)** $\mathbb{C}(x,y,5)=\mathbb{C}(x+y,x-y)$.
Then $\langle x,y,5-5 \rangle=\langle x+y,x-y \rangle$, so $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=0, a_3=5$.

**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)=\mathbb{C}(x+y,x^2+y^2)$ and $\langle x+y,xy \rangle=\langle x+y,x^2+y^2 \rangle$,
so $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=0$.

**(4)** $\mathbb{C}(x^2,x^3)=\mathbb{C}(x)$.
It is easy to see that
$\langle x^2-1,x^3-1 \rangle = \langle x-1 \rangle$,
so $a_1=1,a_2=1,b_1=1$.

**(5)** $\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^3,x^3+y,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
$\langle x^2+y^3-1,x^3+y-1,y \rangle = \langle x-1,y \rangle$,
so $a_1=1,a_2=1,a_3=0,b_1=1,b_2=0$.

**(6)** $\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2,x^3+y^3,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Then
$\langle x^2+y^2-1,x^3+y^3-1,y \rangle = \langle x-1,y \rangle$,
so $a_1=1,a_2=1,a_3=0,b_1=1,b_2=0$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F_1 = 1$ and $G_1 = x,G_2 = x+1$, we have $(F_1 - 0) = (G_1 - 0, G_2 - 0)$ are both the trivial ideal $(1) = \mathbb{C}[x, y]$.

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps the direction from ideals to fraction fields holds for maximal ideals? namely, if there exist $a_i,b_j,\alpha,\beta$ such that $\langle F_i-a_i \rangle =\langle G_j-b_j \rangle= \langle x-\alpha,y-\beta \rangle$, then $\mathbb{C}(F_i)=\mathbb{C}(G_j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. (Actually, it is enough to consider $F_i,a_i$; there is no need to mention $G_j,b_j$).

Comment: Please, is the direction from fraction fields to ideals true? It seems that in MSE there was a proof for arbitrary $F_i$ and specific $G_1=x,G_2=y$. Here I ask about $G_j$ arbitrary also.

Comment: @user237522 you might be overthinking. Please link the MSE post. If you know this fact for arbitrary $F_i$, you may _arbitrarily_ set $F_i = G_i$ to conclude $\mathbb C(G_i) = \mathbb C (x, y)$. Now what you are actually trying to show follows from the transitive property.

Comment: Thank you. The MSE link with Mohan's answer is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723640/generalizing-a-result-in-mathbbcx-to-a-result-in-mathbbcx-y

Comment: I am not sure if Mohan's answer can be generalized to: If $\mathbb{C}(F_i)=\mathbb{C}(G_j)$, then there exist $a_i,b_j \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\langle F_i-a_i \rangle = \langle G_j-b_j \rangle$.  He only deals with: If $\mathbb{C}(F_i)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, then there exist $a_i,b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\langle F_i-a_i \rangle = \langle x-b_1,y-b_2 \rangle$. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Perhaps we should divide to two cases, according to the transcendence degree of $L:=\mathbb{C}(F_i)=\mathbb{C}(G_j)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, whether it is one or two. In case it is two, $L$ can be generated by two elements, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, but we do not have the two generators explicitly, just call them $u$ and $v$. Maybe $\langle F_i-a_2 \rangle=\langle G_j-b_j \rangle=\langle u-c,v-d$, for some $a_i,b_j,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$. I guess the case where the transcendence degree is one is easier.